# Inheritance with EF Code First – Table per Type (TPT)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, table-per-type

I'm tryng to use Table per Type approach to do a inheritance with EF Code First. My actual structure s like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee : Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Document{ get; set; }
}
```

With this structure, for example, I can do this:

```
var obj = new Employee();
string a = obj.Name;   <--- The property Name is from Person model
```

However, is not possible do this kind of relation with the opposite way (like was done in LINQ):

```
var obj2 = new Person();
string b = obj2.Person.Document;    <--- It cannot resolve 'Person' symbol
```

Is there a way to access the model Person from a Employee object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All `Employee` are `Person` but not all `Person` are `Employee`.

Comment: Same way that all `Banana` are `Fruit` but not all `Fruit` are `Banana`.

Comment: Yes. That's right. But some persons are employees. Must have a way to know if I can access the employee model from person. Like 

objEmployee.Person != null ? ((objEmployee)Person).Name : string.Empty;

Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone has mentioned in the comments Person is not an employee and cannot access employee properties. You can use the "as" operator which will convert a person to an employee object if it is an employee, if it is not an employee it will be null.

Hopefully the following will get you in the right direction:

```
var obj2 = new Person();
string b;

var employee = obj2 as Employee;
if (employee != null)
{
    b = obj2.Person.Document;
}
```

In this case Person will never be an employee because it is created right before